# How does Android detect hidden API access from dynamic libraries

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ndk

I have built a Rust library for Android that uses SQLite internally, via Rusqlite:

```
[dependencies]
rusqlite = { version = "0.24.2", features = ["bundled"] }
```

I verified that it only depends on `libc` and `libdl`:

```
llvm-readelf -d target\aarch64-linux-android\debug\libmap_render.so
Dynamic section at offset 0x52768 contains 23 entries:
  Tag                Type           Name/Value
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libdl.so]
  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)       Shared library: [libc.so]
...
```

And its symbol table doesn't contain any SQLite symbols. However the mere act of loading it (I'm using Flutter) like this (this is basically `dlopen()`).

```
DynamicLibrary.open("libmap_render.so")
```

Causes me to get loads of hidden API warnings like this:

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;-><clinit>()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->DEBUG_CLOSE_IDLE_CONNECTIONS:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->sActiveDatabases:Ljava/util/WeakHashMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->CONFLICT_VALUES:[Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, linking, allowed)
Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILandroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory;Landroid/database/DatabaseErrorHandler;IIJLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/-$$Lambda$RBWjWVyGrOTsQrLCYzJ_G8Uk25Q;-><init>(Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->beginTransaction(Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteTransactionListener;Z)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->getThreadSession()Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteSession; (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

I have verified that not loading the library eliminates these errors. The errors really look like it is accessing Java code. But there's no JNI code in my library. It's a plain C library. It has no idea about `WeakHashMap` or `CursorFactory`.

What on earth is going on here? How does Android detect hidden API accesses from dynamically loaded libraries? And why is it saying I'm using a load of Java SQLite APIs when I'm 99% sure I'm not.

[This is the relevant page from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces) but all it has to say on linking is:

> You can inspect your app's log messages to find the following details: The means of access: either linking, via reflection, or via JNI.

Comment: Ok I still have no idea what caused this because I gradually commented out my code until it worked, then added it all back and it still worked. One thing that made this really confusing is that `gradlew clean` did not properly clear all the caches - I needed to use "Invalidate caches and restart" from Android studio. Anyway, something weird was happening and I can't reproduce it now. :-/